# Responsively adjust floating image of unknown width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm working on a blog that has large runs of text with interspersed images that are floating to the right.  In a maximized browser, this looks fine; however, on smaller screens/windows, the text has a tendency to be squashed by the images.  When that happens, I'd like to prevent the text from running on either side of the images, e.g. by setting `float: none` on the images.

The CMS uses `<br><br>` instead of `<p>...</p>`, so we can't easily set a `min-width` on the text.  It looks something like this:

```
<article class="content">
    Text

    <div class="float-right">
        <img>
    </div>

    Text
<article>
```

`.float-right` could be any width, and, in some cases, could change width as the user interacts with the page.

Is it possible to prevent the text from getting "squashed" with just CSS?  If not, I'll likely look into modifying how the CMS generates the HTML; I'd rather not use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Could you provide a CodePen or JSFiddle so we can take a look? Sounds like an interesting problem!

Comment: @RobertAKARobin https://www.namepros.com/blog/inside-interview-why-this-business-owner-paid-650-000-for-furniture-co-uk.979917/  Notice the image in the first post.

Comment: How about a media query? Something like, `@media (max-width:400px){ .float-right{ float:none; }}`

Comment: Can you introduce new elements? It may help to separate this into two divs. Something like `<article><div class="text" /><div class="image" /></article>`

Comment: @RobertAKARobin That's what I'd like to do, but I don't know the size of the contents in advance, so I can't use a fixed number.

Comment: @sytech Not around the text--at least, not easily.

Comment: You don't need to know the size of the contents. `@media (max-width:400px)` refers to the size of the screen. It's saying, "Apply this CSS for any screen smaller than 400px."

Comment: @RobertAKARobin I would need to know the size of the contents to choose the correct value. If the image is 400px wide, `max-width: 400px` wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: What should happen if the screen size is smaller than the width of the image?